# How to integrate Stack Overflow for Teams with Microsoft Teams - "something went wrong" error

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am currently one of the administrators of a Stack Overflow for Teams instance in my company and the main tool for chat, collaboration is Microsoft Teams. So, I was happy to hear about this integration.

1. I have pressed get it now from the [Stack Overflow for Teams app](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200000739).
2. Got logged in using my Microsoft Teams account (firstname.lastname@company.com).
3. Got a link that looks like the following:

https://teams.microsoft.com/dl/launcher/launcher.html?url=%2f_%23%2fl%2fapp%2f4783e622-5303-4ea7-a211-ef0dd405da73%3fsource%3dapp-source&type=app&deeplinkId=2a69e3d3-7706-42ce-8b98-732cfe716221&directDl=true&msLaunch=true&enableMobilePage=true&suppressPrompt=true

3. I was invited to open Microsoft Teams which I did
4. The desktop application opened and the Store (available applications) showed along with the following error:

> Something went wrong.

I have opened the log file (Notification area icon -> Get logs), but I cannot seem to find anything related to this error:

> Command Line State - DeepLink   App subsequent launch - restoring
>   existing app   Starting anonPerfScenario for deeplink   Starting
>   anonPerfScenario for deeplink   Added
>   deeplinkId:a84448fe-cce6-43cd-da97-6ec5e185214c, isMeeting:false and
>   deeplinkType:app   type: commandline-param, deeplinkId:
>   a84448fe-cce6-43cd-da97-6ec5e185214c, isMeeting: false, deeplinkType:
>   app, status: success, scenario: aedafd9e-1bd9-425b-a98e-b50a5132e2e0,
>   scenarioName: deeplink, name: deeplink, step: start, sequence: 0,
>   delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 118081, stepDelta: 0,
>   eventpdclevel: 3, Scenario.Name: deeplink, Scenario.Step: start,
>   Scenario.Status: success,    Not a meetup route. Going through
>   navigation logic.   Deeplink tenantId:undefined Current ADAL tenantId:
>   Is DeeplinkCurrentTenant:true   Sending IPC to deeplink navigate
>   status: success, scenario: aedafd9e-1bd9-425b-a98e-b50a5132e2e0,
>   scenarioName: deeplink, name: deeplink, step: navigate_to_link,
>   sequence: 1, delta: 1, scenarioDelta: 1, elapsed: 118082, stepDelta:
>   1, eventpdclevel: 3, Scenario.Name: deeplink, Scenario.Step:
>   navigate_to_link, Scenario.Status: success,    status: success,
>   scenario: aedafd9e-1bd9-425b-a98e-b50a5132e2e0, scenarioName:
>   deeplink, name: deeplink, step: on_home_tenant, sequence: 2, delta: 1,
>   scenarioDelta: 1, elapsed: 118082, stepDelta: 0, eventpdclevel: 3,
>   Scenario.Name: deeplink, Scenario.Step: on_home_tenant,
>   Scenario.Status: success,    status: success, scenario:
>   aedafd9e-1bd9-425b-a98e-b50a5132e2e0, scenarioName: deeplink, name:
>   deeplink, step: stop, sequence: 3, delta: 1, scenarioDelta: 1,
>   elapsed: 118082, stepDelta: 0, eventpdclevel: 3, Scenario.Name:
>   deeplink, Scenario.Step: stop, Scenario.Status: success,
>   startReason: DeepLink, status: success, scenario:
>   11b2dc98-215a-427f-b40a-5a5b6af6a121, scenarioName:
>   desktop_application_respawn, name: desktop_application_respawn, step:
>   start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 118083,
>   stepDelta: 0, eventpdclevel: 2, Scenario.Name:
>   desktop_application_respawn, Scenario.Step: start, Scenario.Status:
>   success,    startReason: DeepLink, status: success, scenario:
>   11b2dc98-215a-427f-b40a-5a5b6af6a121, scenarioName:
>   desktop_application_respawn, name: desktop_application_respawn, step:
>   stop, sequence: 1, delta: 1, scenarioDelta: 1, elapsed: 118084,
>   stepDelta: 1, eventpdclevel: 2, Scenario.Name:
>   desktop_application_respawn, Scenario.Step: stop, Scenario.Status:
>   success,    Setting the taskbar overlay icon - Available   Focusing
>   main window   Is foreground set to true   Focusing main window   Is
>   foreground set to true   status: success, scenario:
>   6e75aa61-73fa-4e50-b1e0-9ff9644030e7, scenarioName:
>   desktop_local_storage_read, name: desktop_local_storage_read, step:
>   start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, stepDelta: 0,
>   eventpdclevel: 2, Scenario.Name: desktop_local_storage_read,
>   Scenario.Step: start, Scenario.Status: success,    status: success,
>   scenario: 6e75aa61-73fa-4e50-b1e0-9ff9644030e7, scenarioName:
>   desktop_local_storage_read, name: desktop_local_storage_read, step:
>   stop, sequence: 1, delta: 8, scenarioDelta: 8, stepDelta: 8,
>   eventpdclevel: 2, Scenario.Name: desktop_local_storage_read,
>   Scenario.Step: stop, Scenario.Status: success,    status: success,
>   scenario: 5b645998-6341-48b3-8989-1055f22464b3, scenarioName:
>   desktop_app_launch, name: desktop_app_launch, step: start, sequence:
>   0, delta: 1097, scenarioDelta: 1097, elapsed: 1097, stepDelta: 0,
>   eventpdclevel: 2, Scenario.Name: desktop_app_launch, Scenario.Step:
>   start, Scenario.Status: success,    Initialization completed. Loaded
>   config =
>   {"preventUpnDetectSso":false,"currentWebLanguage":"en-US","silentUpdateTriggered":false,"previousCrashesInfo":{"crashes":[]},"windowState":{"monitorId":2841568472,"x":3890,"y":50,"width":1275,"height":1000,"isMaximized":true,"isFullScreen":false},"featureLaunchInfo":{},"restartCommand":{},"launchTime":"1573204770617","isLoggedOut":false,"appPreferenceSettings":{"openAtLogin":true,"openAsHidden":false,"runningOnClose":true,"registerAsIMProvider":true},"isAppFirstRun":false,"isAppSessionEnd":false,"isAppTerminated":false,"isForeground":false,"machineId":"a7fee9212ae113c141e8960493b173944e9e90fd39aa6f05a20f9b8cb4f599b6","deviceInfoId":"469964df1477622d9725c073632e1d3563f03ef4beb638bc1da65be328af68be","restartReason":null,"notificationWindowOnClose":true,"desktopSessionId":"desktop-44daa460-ca77-4cc5-be3c-c497c4ebeb6c"}
>   name: desktop_current_configuration, eventData:
>   {"preventUpnDetectSso":false,"currentWebLanguage":"en-US","silentUpdateTriggered":false,"previousCrashesInfo":{"crashes":[]},"windowState":{"monitorId":2841568472,"x":3890,"y":50,"width":1275,"height":1000,"isMaximized":true,"isFullScreen":false},"featureLaunchInfo":{},"restartCommand":{},"launchTime":"1573204770617","isLoggedOut":false,"appPreferenceSettings":{"openAtLogin":true,"openAsHidden":false,"runningOnClose":true,"registerAsIMProvider":true},"isAppFirstRun":false,"isAppSessionEnd":false,"isAppTerminated":false,"isForeground":false,"machineId":"a7fee9212ae113c141e8960493b173944e9e90fd39aa6f05a20f9b8cb4f599b6","deviceInfoId":"469964df1477622d9725c073632e1d3563f03ef4beb638bc1da65be328af68be","restartReason":null,"notificationWindowOnClose":true,"desktopSessionId":"desktop-44daa460-ca77-4cc5-be3c-c497c4ebeb6c"},
>   eventpdclevel: 2,

The Stack Overflow app does not show in the available applications which might be the cause. Theoretically, I might upload a custom app (it asks for a zip), but I cannot find any zip file for the app.

How can we integrate Stack Overflow for Teams with Microsoft Teams when we get the "something went wrong" error?

Comment: If you are not seeing the app in the MS Teams app store, it may be blocked by your MS Teams admin. If you are still running into issues, please contact support at https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/tickets/new

Comment: @jisoo - indeed it was locked by admins (each app is approved by admin before it can be used). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed Microsoft Teams is being administrated centrally and I had to reach someone to allow this application in order to be able to find it in the app list:

[image: Stack Overflow for Teams in MS Teams]